# How to read a single line

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I have a program that need to read one line from file everytime when it receives a signal SIGUSR2. I made everything except how to read exactly one line.

The content of the file:

```
one
two
three
four
five
...
ten
```

Comment: [This](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) can help you

Comment: Assuming you pass it a sufficiently large buffer, [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) will read you exactly one line

Comment: If you show us the code you have so far, maybe we can help improving it. What have you tried?

Comment: Consider using [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

Comment: Reading `man 7 signal` one learns the only secure method to read from a signal handler is `read()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function....it will read until newline come...or else u can read one char by one char by using fgetc  when u get /n then u can end ur operation of reading

Comment: This is bad advice, as the function in question should be called from a signal handler. Reading `man 7 signal` one learns `fgets()` is not save to be called from a signal handler.

Comment: @alk Could you please quote the lines from `man 7 signal` where they say that? It would be useful to future readers.

Comment: @jean: please see the link I just added to my answer to the OP.

Comment: @alk I saw the link and the list of function. However, I find that writing `Reading man 7 signal one learns…` is very misleading, since that is not the case. If you believe I am mistaken, please, quote the `man 7 signal` page.

Comment: @Jean: Each function **not** on this list is not "*guaranteed*" to be save, so it shall be consider (potentially) unsave. Also please see my updated answer.

Comment: @alk Apparently we don't have the same [man 7 signal](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7) page….

Comment: @Jean: Quoting the footer of the man page you are linking: "*Linux 2.4.18     2002-06-13        SIGNAL(7)*" we see this page **is** somehow outdated.

Comment: @alk Good catch. Indeed. That's why I couldn't find what you were talking about. I first checked on my system (the latest version of MAC OS X) and the man(3) page for signal is similar to the one I linked to. I removed my answer and voted for yours. Maybe the OP will accept it, as it is safer.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP implies the data should be read from a signal handler, the only way to go it to use `read()`, as this is the only function mentioned by recent versions of `man 7 signal` that could be called savely from a signal handler. For details on this please read here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Reading a line via `read()` could be implemented reading byte by byte until an EOL character is found.

As prior to reading it is not clear how much data needs to be read to find an EOL, either a maximum needs to be defined, which then could be used to declare the buffer to read to, or the buffer size needs to be increased dynamically while looping around `read()`.

**Update:**

Excerpt form `man 7 signal` (comment in square brackets by me):

> Async-signal-safe functions
>
> A  signal  handler  function must be very careful, since processing elsewhere may be interrupted at some arbitrary point in the execution of the program.  POSIX has the concept of "safe function".  If a signal interrupts the
>          execution of an unsafe function, and handler calls an unsafe function, then the behavior of the program is undefined.
>
> POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2) requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler:
>
> [list cut out, see link above for the list]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `fscanf()`

```
fscanf(fp, " %[^\n]",buffer);
```

this allow to read one line from your file.

Call it each time you want to read 1 line from your file

**Note:**

1. you have to be carefull when using it. if the line is bigger than the `buffer` size than this will cause overflow. you have to be sure that the buffer size you use is always bigger than each line size.
2. if the line in your file start with white space (defined in the [isspace()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)) then theses spaces will not cpatured

Comment: @TrueY it's not regex. it's format specifier defined by scanf()

Comment: `*scanf()` is a poor choice for reading arbitrary input. You mentioned the two problems with this particular use yourself. `*scanf()` also suffers from very poor error handling. Its use for anything but reading back well-formed stuff which your own code has previously written using `*printf()` is usually discouraged.

Comment: @DevSolar the first note is common with other functions like `fgets()` and I proposed a solution to avoid this problem in my answer. for the second note, if the user file does not contains white spaces at the beginning of each line so the user can use this fscanf without problem

Comment: @MOHAMED: `fgets()` allows to limit the number of characters read (allowing e.g. to `realloc()` more memory, or read the rest of the line in subsequent calls). `*scanf()` simply overflows.

Comment: @DevSolar also `fscanf()` allows to limit the number of characters read. here after an example `fscanf(fp, " %45[^\n]",buffer);`

Comment: This is bad advice, as the function in question should be called from a signal handler. Reading `man 7 signal` one learns `fscanf()` is not save to be called from a signal handler.